# Object = nil, but code still executes inside if statement

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working with Firebase 3.4.0 and am executing this code:

```
if snapshot.value!["username"] != nil {

        self.usernameTextField.text = "\(snapshot.value!["username"]!)"

        print("SNAPSHOT: \(snapshot.value!["username"])")

}
```

I am getting a user's username from the Firebase Realtime Database and, for this user, there is no username given. When the code executes, the two lines inside of the if statement run, but the print line prints "nil".

My firebase data structure:

```
"users": {

    "9Tjjbsj852816": {

        "Email": "test@test.com"

    }
}
```

**If I am running an if statement and the object is nil, why is the code inside the if statement executing?**

Comment: Could the value associated with the key "username" be the string "nil"?

Comment: Check out the data structure from Firebase that I added to my question.

Comment: Could be the value of the string is "" (i.e. empty string) versus nil?

Comment: What I don't understand if why it would be printing out "nil", not ""

Comment: What is the type of `snapshot.value`?  Is it `AnyObject?` perhaps?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is

Comment: So, I believe your problem is that `snapshot.value!["username"]` is `Optional(nil)`.  That is why it isn't equal to `nil`.  To test this theory, try `if snapshot.value!["username"]! != nil {`.

Comment: I tried that, too. Both produce just "nil".

Comment: What does `print(snapshot.value!.dynamicType)` print?

Comment: I can't use dynamicType on snapshot.value!, but I can confirm that it is AnyObject. I figured out my problem and posted the answer. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out with the help of others! Here is the updated if statement. I still can't figure out why Xcode sees a String as nil but not AnyObject.

```
if snapshot.value?["username"] as? String != nil {

    self.usernameTextField.text = "\(snapshot.value!["username"]!!)"

}
```